# Breaking a Function in $L^{\infty}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $f\in L^{\infty}[0,1]$ s.t. $\|f\|_{\infty}=1$
- $E:=\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|<1\}$

> **If** $m(E)>0$, then is it possible to find $g,h\in L^{\infty}[0,1]$ such that $\|g\|_{\infty},\|h\|_{\infty}=1$, $f=\frac{g+h}{2}$ and $f\neq g\neq h$?

**Thoughts:** In $L^1[0,1]$, if $\|f\|_1=1$, then it is possible to break $f$ like wanted. One considers
$$
\phi(x):=\int_0^x|f(x)|\,dx,
$$
which is continuous on $[0,1]$ and such that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$. By the IVT there exists $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $\phi(x_0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $g:=2f1_{[0,x_0]}$ and $h:=2f1_{[x_0,1]}$ work.

In the question we have no integral since $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is the essential supremum. I've been trying to obtain a measurable set $A$ for which $2f1_{A}$ and $2f1_{[0,1]\backslash A}$ would work but I failed.

Comment: You cannot have both $|f|=1$ a.e. and $m(E)>0$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes of course, my bad.

Comment: What about $g=h=f$?

Comment: @nayrb Again, my bad... I want $f\neq g\neq h$.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like a very artificial question.

Comment: @LukasGeyer It will help me to obtain a set of extremal points, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $E_\delta = \{x \in [0,1] : |f(x)| < 1 - \delta \}$ has positive measure. Then define
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x)\cdot(1 + \delta)   \quad (x \in E_\delta) \\
f(x) \quad (x \notin E_\delta)
\end{cases}
$$
and $h(x) = 2f(x) - g(x)$. That should do it.

Comment: Is it correct: $\rm\color{#c00}{1.}$ We can choose such a $\delta$ cause if not every $E_{\delta}$ would have measure $0$ and hence their union $E$ would have measure $0$. $\rm\color{#c00}{2.}$ $\|g\|_{\infty}=1$ because on $E_{\delta}$ its module is $\leq(1-\delta)^2<1$ and $\|f\|_{\infty}=1$ then implies $\|g\|_{\infty}=1$. $\rm\color{#c00}{3.}$ $\|h\|_{\infty}=1$ essentially for the same reason since $h(x)=f(x)$ when $x\not\in E_{\delta}$ and $|h(x)|\leq(1-\delta)^2<1$ on $E_{\delta}$. $\rm\color{#c00}{4.}$ $f\neq g\neq h$ cause they're $f,f\cdot(1+\delta),f\cdot(1-\delta)$ on $E_{\delta}$.

Comment: Those are the missing details, yes.

Comment: Okay, and in $\rm\color{#c00}{4}$ the fact that $m(E_{\delta})>0$ is crucial since otherwise $f,g,h$ *would* be equal, considering that $L^{\infty}$ consists of equivalent classes of functions? Anyway, thanks for the answer, this is very clever!